# How do i set correct filters to request Google Analtyics data

Tags: java, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client, google-analytics-filters

Im using google analytics api java lib
What is correct format for filters?
For example i need to set

1. ga:adContent != (not set)
2. ga:keyword != (not provided)

   ```
   Analytics.Data.Ga.Get statRequest = requestParams.getAnalytics().data().ga().get(  
                       "ga:" + request.getProfile().getId(),  
                       request.getStartDate(),  
                       request.getEndDate(),  
                       request.getMetrics())  
                       .setFilters(filters)  
   String filters;
   ```

Should be  equal:

```
"ga:adContent!=(not%20set);ga:keyword!=(not%20provided)"
```

or

```
"ga%3AadContent!%3D(not%20set)%3Bga%3Akeyword!%3D(not%20provided)"
```

or just

```
"ga:adContent!=(not set);ga:keyword!=(not provided)"
```

Comment: The last one should work. The library should handle the html encoding for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working for me:

```
` ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
    .setViewId(VIEW_ID)
    .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
    .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(pagePath))
    .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(pageviews));

  request.setFiltersExpression("ga:pagePath!=\"<myclientURL>/maths/undergraduate/courses/g100_mathematics.page\";ga:pagePath=@/undergraduate/courses/");`
```

where  is the web address without http:// of my client